# Different website through domain

Tags: html, css, apache, dns, virtualhost

I have a webserver, with 2 virtualhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName main.hu
  LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test.hu/
  LogLevel debug
  ServerAlias test.hu
  ServerName www.test.hu
</VirtualHost>
```

When I query test.hu from any browser, it looks really weird, css looks different, menu is mixed etc. But when I check it with IP address for example 1.2.3.4/test.hu, it looks as it should be.

test.hu points to 1.2.3.4 in DNS.

I'm running a Centos 7 with httpd-2.4.6-18.
Selinux disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are the CSS files loading at all?

Comment: Yes, there are some styles which are loaded, so I think it can read the files (permission, etc).

Comment: Difficult to debug this one without screenshots or working examples.

Comment: Domain : debergabor.hu , same with IP : 178.62.30.55/debergabor.hu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `bootstrap.min.css` files being loaded are not the same in each version.

```
http://178.62.30.55/debergabor.hu/css/bootstrap.min.css

http://debergabor.hu/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

These should be the same but they are not. You have different versions so you have uploaded or linked the wrong files. The first one out of these 2 is the correct one.

So basically, go to where you hosted debergabor.hu, remove the bootstrap.min.css file, then upload the correct one.

Comment: First of all, I've tested it. I renamed bootstrap.min.css to bootstrap.min.css.bak and restarted apache to clear it from memory. Afterwards with IP it was the same mixed website. But.. I do not understand how can I solve this issue because http://178.62.30.55/debergabor.hu/css/bootstrap.min.css and http://debergabor.hu/css/bootstrap.min.css are the same file on the server. Each are /var/www/html/debergabor.hu/css/bootstrap.min.css.

Comment: Hmm, but you are right, I've checked the sources and it shows different of the website...

Comment: The files are not the same. Completely delete the bootstrap.min.css from the http://debergabor.hu/ because that one is wrong. (I mean actually take the file and put it in the trash). Then, make sure you have a boostrap.min.css file that includes `.navbar-fixed-bottom` by doing a quick search in the file, then that's the one you want, so upload that one.

Comment: I've checked the file on the server, but only the website with IP request is changed. What kind of sorcery is this? :)

Comment: When Centos 7 came out I found some httpd bugs related to redhat cluster, this could be similar? :/

Comment: Try linking a hosted version instead: //maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: Yes that's fixed it. Remember to do a forced browser refresh to clear the cache when you're looking at it.

Comment: And it works now.. But still, how could it be if we are talking about one file?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Without looking in more depth at the way the files are setup on the server. Seeing as I had to do a forced refresh to see the final working version, it could well be to do with browser caching which would be to do with the `.htaccess`. If you still want to host the file yourself, try changing it to a different name such as boostrap-styles.css then link to that.

Comment: After renaming bootstrap.min.css to bootstrap2.css and relinked in index.html, it works without problem. I'm not the developer of this  site just doing the infrastructure part. I think somewhere in the program code it's overwritten by something. I have to talk with the developer. Really thanks for the help Cooper!

Comment: Cool. Probably a caching problem then.